# Are these two pointer types really incompatible?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, function-pointers

I have the following `typedef` and higher order function:

```
typedef void block_fn (struct block*, block_sector_t, void* buffer);

static void block_apply (struct page* page, block_fn *block_fn) {
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < PAGE_SECTORS; i++) {
    block_fn(swap.device, page->sector * PAGE_SECTORS + i, page_kpage(page)
             + i * BLOCK_SECTOR_SIZE);
  }
}
```

And I call it in the following two places:

```
block_apply (page, &block_write);
...
block_apply (page, &block_read);
```

`block_read` and `block_write` have the following signatures:

```
void block_read (struct block *, block_sector_t, void *);
void block_write (struct block *, block_sector_t, const void *);
```

This causes GCC to complain:

> ../../vm/swap.c:94:13: note: expected `void (*)(struct block *, block_sector_t,  void *)` but argument is of type `void (*)(struct block *, block_sector_t,  const void *)`

Is GCC right to be angry? Is it safe to pass this function pointer in this way?

EDIT: I understand that these two function pointers are of different types. My question is whether or not it is *safe* to use them in this way: can it trigger undefined behavior? Is there a case where passing a function pointer with an incompatible type in this way will cause something unexpected to happen?

Comment: why don't you change this function call to and give a try?
void block_write (struct block *, block_sector_t, void *);

Comment: I don't think GCC is complaining about your function pointer.  It is complains about you are trying to make the `void *` to a `const void *`.

Comment: Yes, it is. If it wasn't there would be no point in having this distinction; right?

Comment: um ... may i ask why you redefine `void`?? Not only will this cause massive confusion to every reader, it is also be very likely error-prone. Redefining primitives and pseudo-primitives is ALWAYS a very bad idea, if it even compiles. Instead, you should give your function-pointer type an ALIAS. Im guessing you havent looked up the spec about `typedef` yet.

Comment: @specializt that `typedef` is a function pointer type, not redefining `void`.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Does that mean that this kind of function pointer is unsafe to use? Or is the warning meaningless in this case?

Answer (score 3):

yes, it's right to complain in general, though not meaningful in your case

by saying const void *, you are declaring that the function will not modify the
pointed-to data.  By omitting const, you are saying that it might.

The function signature is a contract between the caller and the callee, that the compiler
enforces.  The compiler prevents the code from advertising a stricter signature than it
implements (eg, advertising read-only arguments when it writes to them.)

In your case, though, you just want a pointer to a function with limited type checking.

You could declare the type as taking const void *, and override the const with a type cast
when you invoke it.

Comment: Better take it by `void*` and add `const` if needed. It's safer.

Comment: isn't that what is done now, it takes a void* and the compiler complains?

Comment: Not quite. At the moment, there are two function signatures, one with a `const void*`, the other with a `void*`, and the compiler complains about whichever one does not fit. Your proposal forces at least one cast, in the writer-function. Going the other way means no casts.

Comment: wait, do you mean change the prototype of block_read?  that would work.  I was suggesting to cast in block_apply() and changing the block_fn typedef, and leaving the reader/writer functions as is.

Comment: Yes. Always avoid casts, they smell of danger.

Comment: "though not meaningful in your case" -- does that mean that this kind of incompatible pointer is always safe to use? Is that guaranteed by the standard? Are there optimizations that the compiler can do that will break this code?

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that the `const void`* function is in library code -- I'm hesitant to change it for my purpose.

Comment: "not meaningful" because in _this_ case it is always safe to use:  you are passing in the actual function to apply along with the buffer to use, almost as if you were invoking it locally.  `const` marks the argument read-only, but you want a typedef for a function that will either only read or also write its argument.  C considers the two distinct and incompatible, so to pass the two functions via a single parameter you either have to weaken the typedef (eg omit the const) or override the function signatures (cast them to some mutually compatible type, eg void*).

Comment: or you could have block_apply take two function pointers, block_fn_ro and block_fn_rw (read-only and read-write), and have block_apply call whichever one is non-null.  That plays nice with all the type declarations, but is more awkward.

Answer (score 0):

The two pointer types are incompatible.

IMO, it is not safe to pass this function pointer in this way.

Higher level code knows what type `block_apply()` can handle because of its function signature.  To pass a different type to `block_apply()` necessitates 2 things: 1) higher level code defeating the signature (casting) and 2) higher level code knowing that it is OK to do so.

Better to not oblige the higher level code from casting and relieve it of the burden of knowing the inner workings of `block_apply()`.

---

To avoid casts, code could create another function `block_apply_const()`.  Then call `block_apply(page, &block_read)`  and `block_apply_const(&block_write)` as needed.

```
typedef void block_fn_const (struct block*, block_sector_t, const void* buffer);

static void block_apply_const (struct page* page, block_fn_const *block_fn) {
   // same code
}
```

But that duplicates code.

Alternatively, a wrapper function could perform the cast.  This is better than littering higher level code with calls to `block_apply()` with casts.  Since casting should be done with caution and these `static` functions know that it is OK to do the cast, code here can do it.

```
static void block_apply_const (struct page* page, block_fn_const *block_fn) {
   block_apply(page, (block_fn) block_fn);
}
```

Comment: "IMO, it is not safe to pass this function pointer in this way." -- are there any optimizations that the compiler can do that will cause unintended behavior for this code? That's really my question here. Is it actually unsafe?

Comment: @Patrick Collins 1) Say your machine uses [Harvard_architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture`)  (Used on PICs 2014).  Then a pointer to constant memory and a pointer to normal memory could have the same value but point to different locations (ROM vs. RAM).  Your code and my second solution both fail as a pointer to constant memory and dynamic memory cannot be simply casted.  My first solution with "// same code" would work.

Comment: More  2) As  @Deduplicator  said smells of danger when casting.  When creating a suite of functions, calling routines should not  perform casting to trick the functions.  Any tricks, if any, should happen within the suite.